I am using tflite_flutter package and I am getting error while converting to tensor image to format for processing it the model and labels in assets
The main problem is that while integrating the tflite model to my app. I am getting range error index as 16 since my labels goes from 0-15. only the problem is in the way it is processing the image and converting to tensor image. I want to just show output based on labels the image matches with conditions as: height: 256, width: 256, batchSize: 32, Channels: 3, Color format: BGR. the models and labels are already there in assets folder.
I tried to load my models and labels first then convert image to tensor image, then pass the value to model which will return the index from given image which will be mapped from labels to produce correct output from 0-15 and its corresponding values. I am expecting correct tensor image conversion and correct output based on input given image.
GitHub link
